# Migrating Java UNO code from OpenOffice 2.4 to 3.0

Tags: java, openoffice.org, spreadsheet, uno

I had a nifty small tool written to convert spreadsheets to plain text.
Since it was my private hacker tool, it relied on OpenOffice 2.x to read the files.

But when I installed **OpenOffice 3** and tried to get it get it to run, I failed miserably, because I'm either missing some JAR files or half the classes have been replaced.

I'm including all five JAR files from URE/Java (URE: [UNO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Network_Objects) 
Runtime Environment, a subset of OpenOffice.org hosting and 
managing UNO components) and am still missing these classes:

```
com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader
com.sun.star.frame.XController
com.sun.star.frame.XDesktop
com.sun.star.frame.XModel
com.sun.star.frame.XStorable
com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheet
com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheetDocument
com.sun.star.sheet.XSpreadsheetView
com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument
```

Any pointers?

Comment: That's not good...  I was intending on doing some UNO coding, but if the interface isn't stable, I'll have to rethink that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was missing.

I had to include the following jars

```
URE/java/juh.jar
URE/java/jurt.jar
URE/java/ridl.jar
Basis/program/classes/unoil.jar
```

The last one I was missing before - *note the German OOo version*.

And, something I didn't have to do before, I had to include the path to the OOo executables, e.g.

```
c:/program/OpenOffice.org 3/program/
```

After that and without changing code it worked just like before.

So, Brian, UNO's API is stable even between major releases. It was just the classpath I had to fix.